# NetBeans shows no errors but it is not really commiting changes to GitHub

Tags: netbeans, github, commit

I have never used GitHub before. As Google Code is going to cease operations I started to move my projects to GitHib as Google suggested. I created a project, "cloned" it in my PC using NetBeans, added a folder with a few files and commited the changes. NetBeans does not show any error message and the Show Changes command shows no changes after the commit ends but when I check GitHub or make another "clone" I can see that my files are not there.

This is the log of my commit operation.

==[IDE]== Mar 18, 2015 1:28:18 PM Committing...

### Git Commit

git add C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\instalacion-windows.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\instalacion-linux.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\operacion-jee1.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\meta-programacion-jee1.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\referencia.pdf
git commit -m moving from google code C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\instalacion-windows.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\instalacion-linux.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\operacion-jee1.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\meta-programacion-jee1.pdf C:\Users\Jorge\Projects\github\adalid-jee1\wiki\documents\referencia.pdf
Commit Log
revision   : 7783a4b224318167a36f70b28287717e7000fdc6
author     : jrcampins 
date       : Mar 18, 2015 1:28:18 PM
summary    : moving from google code

INFO: End of Commit

==[IDE]== Mar 18, 2015 1:28:18 PM Committing... finished.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Jamie Murai (GitHub staff), and I quote "You mentioned that you committed in NetBeans, but did you also push? A commit is just a local operation, pushing sends the changes to GitHub"

As I mentioned I had never used GitHub before so I assumed commit would save my changes in GitHub, but it doesn't, it is a local operation. Changes have to be "pushed" (In Netbeans: Team / `Remote / Push...) in order to save them in the repository.